# What I said is wrong

Tags: verb-agreement

Which one is correct:

What I said **is** wrong.

What I said **was** wrong.

Comment: 'Which one is correct?' assumes that one and only one is. 'What I said was wrong' is certainly correct, but often – perhaps usually – carries the sense 'I said some bad things about ...'. 'What I said is wrong' means that 'I stated as fact something that isn't true' (eg I said the moon was/is made of green cheese). It's talking about enduring truth, spoken of at some time in the past. The NIV has “If what I said is wrong, bear witness about the wrong ..." [Jesus]

Comment: What *was* wrong probably still *is* wrong.

Comment: It depends on whether you just said it or said it awhile back.

Comment: Both are correct.  However, this question is probably more suitable for ELL.SE.

Comment: In short, no one is going to mind very much which one you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on context.

-"What I said was wrong" emphasizes the fact that it was wrong at the moment I spoke.  e.g. I said Mary would be waiting for you but what I said was wrong (she wasn't waiting for you)

-"What I said is wrong" emphasizes the fact that it is wrong at the present moment and at any time.  "I said the square root of 144 is 19. What I said is wrong."

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Edwin Ashworth, "what I said **was** wrong" can carry the connotation that *saying it* was wrong.  (It wasn't a nice thing to say; it hurt someone's feelings, I'm sorry I said it). This coukd be a part of an *apology*.  This does not mean that he said something *untrue*, just that it was *inappropriate* to say at that time and place. That is, "wrong" means *untactful*.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/untactful

Saying "what I said **is** wrong" is much more straightforward; it will generally be heard as referring to the falsehood of the speaker's previous statement, not the advisability of saying it.  That is, "wrong" means *incorrect*.